# String concat with conditional (Thymeleaf + SpringEL)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the object product with type (string) and trade (boolean).
I want to append the product type and "trade" if trade is true.

The code is working:

```
th:classappend="${product.type}"
```

As well as:

```
th:classappend="${product.trade}? trade"
```

But I want to concat both and I'm failing at with.

Example of what I want but I didn't find how to.

```
th:classappend="${product.type} + ${product.trade}? trade"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and tell me if this worked for you

```
th:classappend="${product.trade ? 'Trade'  +' '+ product.type : product.type}"
```

Comment: Awesome dude! It worked with an adjustment: ${product.trade ? 'Trade' +' '+ product.type : product.type}. Can you explain me the second part? "product.type : product.type" I don't understand this sintax, why can't we just use "product.type"? Thank you very much, so bad I don't have enough reputation to upvote, hope someone does!

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you. The expression that I wrote is in the form of "boolean statement ? result if true : result if false " , so if product.trade is true then have as classappend Trade and empty space and tha value of product.type otherwise have only the value of product.type. Hope it makes sense. Let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: Yeah, I got it. For some reason I was understanding the boolean statement as ending after trade. But then after your explanation I realized that everything is part of the boolean statement and it was kinda obvious what's happening. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div th:if="${product.trade == true}" th:text="${product.type}"></div>
```

or

```
<div th:with="flag = ${product.trade == true}"></div>

<div th:if="${flag}" th:text="${product.type}></div>

<div th:unless="${flag}" text="flag is false"></div>
```

or

```
<div th:if="${product.trade == true}">
    <span th:text="${product.type}"> </span> trade
</div>
```